# Spring Boot 2.4 RSocket detect lost connection repeatedly

Tags: spring, rsocket

I connect with a RsocketClient to a RsocketServer with the following configuration. This works well. I would like to detect the loss of connection. This works well by registering to the OnClose Mono of the underlying rsocket of the RsocketClient. But only for one time. How can I detect the closing if I have repeated connection losses and reconnections?

```
requester = rsocketRequesterBuilder.setupRoute("shell-client").setupData(CLIENT_ID)
                        .setupMetadata(accessToken, BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE)
                        .rsocketStrategies(rsocketStrategies).
                        rsocketConnector(connector -> connector.acceptor(responder).reconnect(Retry.backoff(1000, Duration.ofMillis(500)).doBeforeRetry(x->{log.info("Retry");
                        
                        
                        
                        }).doAfterRetry(x->{log.info(x.toString());})))
                        .tcp("x.y.z.40", 8080);
                
               
                RSocket r=requester.rsocketClient().source().block();
                r.onClose().doOnError(x->{
                    log.info("Error");}).doFinally(x->{
                    log.info("Disconnected");
                }).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may achieve the required behaviour using the following piece of code:

```java
 requester
       .rsocketClient()
       .source()
       .flatMap(rsocket -> rsocket.onClose())
       .repeat()
       .retry()
       .subscribe();
```

in the above example, once the connection is lost, the `rsocket.onClose()` will be sending a terminal signal. Since you have installed the reconnect feature, the next subscription to the `RSocketClient.source()` will result in the connection reestablishment. Therefore, once that happens, you will receive a new rsocket instance and will subscribe to `onClose` stream again inside `flatMap` operator.

To make this operation repeated, we can use `.repeat` and `retry` so whenever `onClose` terminates (which is the indicator of disconnection) the subscription to `RSocketClient.source` will be repeated and you will able to obtain a new connection and start listening to the `onClose` stream again